What is the correct way to use addr2line for a Linux PIE program?
We have raw addresses from a Linux program's call stack, but how do we use addr2line to convert the addresses if the program is a position-independent executable (PIE)?
In Windows, we can record the in-memory base address of the module, then do simple addition or subtraction to get an address that works with a .pdb file.

in which way do you get your stack trace? If it's from a core dump, that usually includes the memory map. If the process is still running, you can also see the current memory mapping (which isn't necessarily the same as when you got the stack trace) in /dev/{pid}/maps. But what you really need is a core dump, which also contains all the symbols, and other state, and can be directly inspected (e.g. using gdb).

@MarcusMüller We get it using libunwind.  We already record the contents of /proc/self/maps.  I just don't know how to use the data properly.

you can use the x (executable) marked segment's address as offset address for addr2line.
